# Is there a way to use an "Id"-property in a derived class when I have the BsonId-attribute for another property in the base type?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I can use an Id-property in the baseclass, but when I wan't to do this in a derived class, I will get an error "The property 'Id' of type 'ConsoleApp1.DerivedWithId' cannot use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property 'IdForMongo' of type 'ConsoleApp1.BaseWithoutId"
Below is a Console-app to illustrate

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This will work
            BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(DerivedWithoutId));

            //But this will throw error: The property 'Id' of type 'ConsoleApp1.DerivedWithId' cannot use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property 'IdForMongo' of type 'ConsoleApp1.BaseWithoutId
            BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(DerivedWithId));
        }
    }

    public class BaseWithoutId
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid IdForMongo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseWithId
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid IdForMongo { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedWithId : BaseWithoutId
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedWithoutId : BaseWithId
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an event based system where I am trying out MongoDb as a store. I have a baseclass DomainEvent for events that events inherit from. In the events I would sometime like to use Id as a property. E.g. for the event ItemAddedEvent (that derives from DomainEvent) I want to hava a property Id that should reflect the Id of the Item which is added

Comment: @SBFrancies I think he wants to have a class with an Id property (DerivedWithId in the example) that derives from a base class that contains an [BsonId] property (BaseWithoutId.IdForMongo in the example). [BsonId] will be the _id in Mongo, but when you have a class with an Id property that derives from another class with [BsonId] the framework says that there is already an _id. Seems almost like a bug in the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the [BsonNoId] attribute in your derived class.

```
[BsonNoId]    
public class DerivedWithId : BaseWithoutId
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My simple Console-application seems to work with this solution. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a fluent way to do this?